# jQuery add attribute with backslash

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add the input dynamically, with custom html5 validation. The jQuery code is as below.

```
$('#test').html('<input type="text" name="test_input" id="test_input" required pattern="\d*" title="Please Enter Valid No.">');
```

but in html output looks like this:

```
<input type="text" name="test_input" id="test_input" required pattern="d*" title="Please Enter Valid No.">
```

instead of `\d*` it is coming `d*`.

Comment: Just use a double `\\ `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape the slash `\`:

```
$('#test').html('<input type="text" name="test_input" id="test_input" required pattern="\\d*" title="Please Enter Valid No.">');
```

or you can also write character code for `\` i.e, `&#92;` like:

```
$('#test').html('<input type="text" name="test_input" id="test_input" required pattern="&#92;d*" title="Please Enter Valid No.">');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ougn8rc5/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Use with escape character i.e. `\`

```
$('#test').html('<input type="text" name="test_input" id="test_input" required pattern="\\d*" title="Please Enter Valid No.">');
```